# Combobox Enter or Tab Press

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA My project, combobox keypress enter or tab not working.But ESC press working

Codes;

```
Private Sub cmbCariler_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   If KeyAscii = 9 Or KeyAscii = 13 Then
      MsgBox "run"
   End If
EndSub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right event. You want the KeyDown event.

```
Private Sub cmbCariler_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
   If KeyCode = 9 Or KeyCode = 13 Then
      MsgBox "keycode"
   End If
End Sub
```